# WordPressテーマのAvadaで Too few arguments が表示される

Tags: php, wordpress

ヘッダーの上部と、各固定ページのコンテンツ編集部分に添付の赤枠で囲ったエラーが出てしまいます。このエラーに書かれているphpの130行目の内容はこちらです。

```php
'description' => sprintf( esc_html__( 'Controls the left and right padding for page content when using 100&#37; site width, 100&#37; width page template or 100&#37; width post option. This does not affect Fusion Builder containers.  Enter value including any valid CSS unit, ex: 30px. %s', 'Avada' ), Avada()->settings->get_default_description( 'hundredp_padding' ) ),
```

このphpはAvadaの親テーマの中に入っているもので、ダウンロードしたままで書き換えていません。
ちなみに、プラグインはAvada推奨のものしか使用していません。

解決方法を教えてくださる方、よろしくお願いします。

[image: Avadaのテーマ エラー]

Comment: 質問を見てくださった方、ありがとうございます。色々調べていたら、このようなエラーは言語ファイルによるエラーが多いことがわかりました。言語ファイルを色々削除して試したところ、avadaのテーマを日本語化するファイルでエラーが出ておりました。解決しましたので、大丈夫です。ありがとうございました。質問を削除する方法や質問を終了する方法が分からないので、こちらに追記させていただきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: こんにちは、はじめまして。質問を完了するには自分で、解決した内容をコメントして、解決マークをいれていただけると後に同じ問題でサイトを訪問した方が、解決済みの問題として参照しやすくなります、お時間あるときにご対応ください。

Answer (score 1):

(解決済みとのことですが)

表示されているのは管理画面内であり、 Warning、すなわち警告なので実用上の問題はないでしょう。

表示されている警告は

> **Warning** sprintf(): Too few arguments in (エラー箇所)

です。これは`sprintf()`の引数(フォーマット文字列)内でプレースホルダ(`%s`など)が複数回使用されている場合などに、その後の引数で指定されているフォーマット引数が不足していることを示します。

これには`%`も対象であるため、フォーマット文字列内で`%`を使用する際は`%%`が利用できるのですが、当該コードの原文では代わりに実体参照形式の`&#37;`が用いられているようです。
また、`esc_html__`は翻訳とHTMLエスケープをおこないます。
当該テーマを所有しているわけではないので推測になりますが、日本語の翻訳ファイルにおいて当該文字列のパーセント記号が`%%`や`&#37;`ではなく`%`として翻訳されていたためにこの警告が表示されていると考えられます。